# GTX 590 temperature is 71/61 degree celsius

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, temperature

I'm a bit concerned about the idling temperatures of my graphics card, GPU-Z says that its temperature is 62°C for one and 72°C for the other (it lists two GTX 590s but I only have one so not sure why that is).

The Asus tool reports 61°C as the temperature also.

Fan speed is at 47% (1800RPM).

At heavy use it can go as high as 90°C

Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: I'd be pretty inclined to suspect GPU-Z is making a mistake. Have you been having GPU issues? Have you been hearing dying fan sounds?

Comment: No everything is fine, the fan is always whirring pretty hard though. The Asus tool is also suggesting 60 degrees...

Comment: It lists 2 because the GTX 590 is essentially 2 GPU's in one.

Comment: The reason CPU-Z lists two GTX 590s is because the 590 has two GPUs on one board. This is essentially true for all of the top-of-the-range graphics cards released by AMD or nVidia: rather than squeeze more horsepower out of the core (in this case, the GF110 core), they just slam another one in and SLI (or Crossfire, in AMD's case) the two together. So, if you SLI'ed another 590 in there, you'd strictly be doing what's called Quad-SLI.

Comment: The maximum temperature for that card is 97. 90 is concerning

Comment: I should add that this means that all of the standard performance 'quirks' of SLI apply to the GTX 590 (and any other card that does this). Not all games gain equally from SLI tech, and some games actually show no improvement at all. In those cases, the 590 at stock clock speeds will actually run slower than a 580, which is clocked higher from the factory. However, SLI is getting better and more supported over time, so the number of games that don't benefit is going ever downwards.

Comment: NVidia runs with lava. I know, I have NVidia cards in my computers. But there is nothing wrong with that. The fan may be a bit loud, but they run for years and years without any problem. (Never changed fans or anything, since every card I bought came with a 5 year warranty.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GTX590 is known to run hot, even after firmware updates to address the problem. If you look at t[his review](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/reviews/1138/pg17/asus-nvidia-geforce-gtx-590-graphics-card-launch-review-power-temp-noise-oc.html), the load temperature is nothing particularly to worry about.

However, you can take steps to improve the situation:

- Make sure that your case airflow is good, and that reasonable cool air is delivered to the card intake fan.
- Update the card firmware to take advantage of any cooling improvements
- remove the card heatsink and fan, and clear away/replace the thermal grease with a decent after-market alternative (e.g. [Arctic Silver 5](http://www.arcticsilver.com/as5.htm) (AS5)) - will invalidate warranty
- replace the HSF with an aftermarket cooler - but will invalidate the warranty, and I don't even know if there are aftermarket solutions for such a limited-run card.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/index.htm). It is a very handy GPU monitoring *and overclocking* program which shows your GPU's temperature, GPU 1 and 2 usage, fan speed, etc.

My Asus GTX 590 has a temperature of about 40 - 43°C in idle (depends on room temperature). So 62°C is very high for just being idle in my opinion.

Try installing the latest drivers and adjust your fan speed configuration with the MSI Afterburner program.

You could try to affix a fan to your case to blow air directly on your GPU for extra cooling. My card is air cooled.